# rvm is not a function because gnome-terminal run bash as a no-login shell?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, rvm

I am installing rvm with

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

But when installed, run rvm return rvm is not a function, because gnome-terminal run as no-login shell as default, therefore skipping /etc/pro file*.

So are there any ways to run bash as login shell in my remote server?Or any other ways to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you read this? https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev yes, I refer this post and know that what is the problem, I have try this method in my local machine, but I want to solve this problem in my ECS

Answer (score 3):

you need to check the option "*Run as login shell*" in the Gnome terminal's settings. 
Here: https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal

Alternatively for `rvm is not a function`:

quick solution:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

One time fix, in your bashrc add:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I have seen this (type of) question asked a lot of times at SO, and the solutions are nonetheless same. I will just try to explain the reason behind the error and what the fixes actually does:

- When running as a login shell, Bash will read `~/.bash_profile` (or, if that doesn't exist, `~/.profile`) on startup.
- When running as a non-login shell, Bash will read `~/.bashrc`.

As the above link to rvm's site explains:

> Multi-User RVM creates a script in /etc/profile.d, which is being
>   sourced on startup. Also, most people put the RVM sourcing line required to load RVM in their ~/.bash_profile for Single-User installs. By default, gnome-terminal runs Bash as usual, as
>   a non-login shell, therefore skipping /etc/profile* and executing only
>   the user's  ~/.bashrc.

Therfore the two kinds of solutions are either `run as login shell` or load rvm from `~/.bashrc` by editing it.

Comment: I have read that post before I ask the question, I do solve the problem in my local machine with the method in that picture. But I have a ECS, so I can not use the method. How to edit `~/.bashrc` to execute `/etc/profile.d`?

Comment: you will need `sudo` priviledge for that. supposing you have vim, do this: `sudo vim ~/.bashrc` then at the end of the file add the line in my answer. Then reload the bashrc using `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: you mean `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`? This will not help, because `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` doesn't exist. In my local machine, this folder is create after I check the 'Run command as login shell' checkbox

Comment: `~/.rvm` is created when you install rvm and not when you check `Run command as login shell`. Think for yourself, how can giving permission to gnome terminal create a rvm folder?

Comment: I have tried to install for multi-user with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable`, rvm is installed

Comment: what does `echo $rvm_path` return?

Comment: then put `[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"` in your bashrc